# debian packaging: what's the difference between dh build and dh binary

Tags: linux, debian, package, deb, debhelper

I encountered an issue when building debian package.

As for the document of the rules file: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#rules

- debian/rules build runs dh build; which in turn runs the following:

  ```
  dh_testdir
  dh_auto_configure
  dh_auto_build
  dh_auto_test
  ```
- fakeroot debian/rules binary runs fakeroot dh binary; which in turn runs the following:

  ```
  dh_testroot
  dh_prep
  dh_installdirs
  dh_auto_install
  dh_install
  dh_installdocs
  ...
  dh_builddeb
  ```

But when I run `dh binary --no-act` command, the output includes `dh build --no-act`. This means the `./configure` and `make` commands are run two times during build the debian package. It's weird.

I used `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc` to build debian package.

UPDATE: I saw it actually did not run twice, but why --no-act shows the `dh build` output runs twice?

Answer (score 6):

First, to answer the first question, the differences between the `debian/rules` `build` and `binary` rules are outlined in [Debian Policy §4.9](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules). In brief, the `build` target should only perform "building" steps, and not do anything that requires root (or fakeroot) privileges, such as chowning files to uid 0 or "installing" things. `binary`, on the other hand, should take all the necessary steps to build the appropriate binary debs. **`binary` should include all the steps of `build` if they haven't already been done.**

Here are a couple facts about `dh` that you might be missing:

1. `dh` keeps track of the `dh_*` commands that get run as part of a build sequence (for example, as part of `dh build` or `dh binary`), even between invocations. You can see what commands it thinks it has already run by looking at the contents of `debian/$package.debhelper.log`. If a command is listed in there, `dh` will consider it already run for the purposes of command sequencing.
2. `dh $sequence --no-act` takes that `debian/$package.debhelper.log` file into account as well. So when you run `dh binary --no-act` on a fresh, clean build dir, you'll see a long list of commands, including those that need to be done for the `build` target. But if you actually *run* `dh build` first and *then* try `dh binary --no-act`, it won't show the build steps anymore. It will only show the steps for preparing and creating the actual .deb package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think the document should point this out in order not to confuse new users.